# Need help understanding the behaviour of SELECT ... FOR UPDATE causing a deadlock

Tags: oracle, jpa, deadlock

I have two concurrent transactions executing this bit of code (simplified for illustration purposes):

```
@Transactional
public void deleteAccounts() {
    List<User> users = em.createQuery("select u from User", User.class)
                         .setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
                         .getResultList();
    for (User user : users) {
        em.remove(user);
    }
}
```

My understanding is that one of the transactions, say transaction A, should execute the SELECT first, lock all the rows it needs and then go on with the DELETEs while the other transaction should wait for A's commit before performing the SELECT. However, this code is deadlocking. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What is the exception message for the deadlock?

Comment: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

Error Code: 60

Comment: Do you have relationships between users there?

Comment: No. There are @OneToOne, cascading, relationships with other entities, though.

Comment: Are you sure there are no other entity types locked in another concurrent transaction? Can you confirm that this happens regularly?

Comment: These are the only transactions executing, but for testing purposes I made them execute once per second. So in theory there may be more than 2 concurrent transactions executing this code.

Answer (score 1):

The USER table probably has a lot of foreign keys referring to it.  If any of them are un-indexed Oracle will lock the entire child table while it deletes the row from the parent table.  If multiple statements run at the same time, even for a different user, the same child tables will be locked.  Since the order of those recursive operations cannot be controlled it is possible that multiple sessions will lock the same resources in a different order, causing a deadlock.

See [this section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/consist.htm#CNCPT88978) in the Concepts manual for more information.

To resolve this, add indexes to any un-indexed foreign keys.  If the column names are standard a script like this could help you find potential candidates:

```
--Find un-indexed foreign keys.
--
--Foreign keys.
select owner, table_name
from dba_constraints
where r_constraint_name = 'USER_ID_PK'
    and r_owner = 'THE_SCHEMA_NAME'
minus
--Tables with an index on the relevant column.
select table_owner, table_name
from dba_ind_columns
where column_name = 'USER_ID';
```

Comment: Nitpick: There might be several users in the DB who own a constraint named 'USER_ID_PK', so this query might return false positives. I'd recommend adding `and r_owner = ...` to the first sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE JPA generally traslate it to SELECT FOR UPDATE this make a lock in the database, not necessary for a row it depends of the database and how you configure the lock, by default the lock is by page or block not for row, so check your database documentation to confirm the how your database make the lock, also you can change it so you can apply the lock for a row.
When you call the method deleteAccounts it starts a new transaction and the lock will be active until the transaction commit (or rollback) in this case when the method has finished, if other transaction want to acquire the same lock it can't and I think this is why you have the dead lock, I suggest you to try annother mechanism maybe an optimistic lock, or a lock by entity.

You can try given a timeout to the acquire the lock so:

```
em.createQuery("select u from User", User.class)
.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
.setHint("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 5000)
.getResultList();
```

I found a good [article](http://oracle-error.blogspot.in/2008/10/ora-00060-deadlock-detected-while_20.html) that explains better this error, it is cause by the database:

> Oracle automatically detects deadlocks and resolves them by rolling
>   back one of the transactions/statements involved in the deadlock, thus
>   releasing one set of resources/data locked by that transaction. The
>   session that is rolled back will observe Oracle error: ORA-00060:
>   deadlock detected while waiting for resource. Oracle will also produce
>   detailed information in a trace file under database's UDUMP directory.
>
> Most commonly these deadlocks are caused by the applications that
>   involve multi table updates in the same transaction and multiple
>   applications/transactions are acting on the same table at the same
>   time. These multi-table deadlocks can be avoided by locking tables in
>   same order in all applications/transactions, thus preventing a
>   deadlock condition.

Comment: "if other transaction want to acquire the same lock it can't" - but then there would be a timeout, not a deadlock, right? Because this newer transaction hasn't acquired anything yet, so there should be no reason for a deadlock.

Comment: Yes it's true, but you can specify a timeout of 0, it's a strange behaviour but if you see the exception is the database that throws the deadlock saying deadlock detected while waiting for resource, maybe you can specifiy a timeout of 5 seconds only for test.

Comment: It's vendor provider to configure the time of how long wait for a lock, you can specify the value of timeout as hint, I edit my answer to show an example.

Comment: It fails with a deadlock _before_ the timeout has expired.

Comment: After Google the error code I found an article that explains better why the error ocurrs in Oracle, I edit my answer with the link

Comment: I know what a deadlock is. The problem is that I don't know what's causing it in my scenario and I'd like to understand what's wrong with my rationale.

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code and in the way you implement it, I recommend you as the article says "Action: Look at the trace file to see the transactions and resources involved. Retry if necessary." I think this could be the first step to figured out what is the real problem.